# How to get the CR95HF NFC reader to work in the Linux NFC stack

Tags: linux

I have a board with a CR95HF device: A bare implementation directly connected to a UART.
I have been searching how to get this to work or even how to proceed and test all this. No luck so far. There is virtually no documentation at all how to implement a driver for the Linux NFC stack.

The only driver that looks a bit what I seem to need is the Marvell driver in the kernel source tree that maybe looks what I need: source/drivers/nfc/nfcmrvl/... ? Or am I completely looking in the wrong direction?

Note: I also found a patch set of 6 patches to get the ST95HF working with a uart: https://spinics.net/lists/linux-wireless/msg161928.html
But here they say it is based on a deprecated LDISC mechanism and that is why it was never accepted to the mainline kernel.
(I Applied the patch, + dts changes, but it looks like the code is never called.)

Also I have no idea what I need on the userspace side and how the NFC stack should be called from any tool from userspace.

So to be concrete:

- Is there any documentation or skeleton implementation to create a driver according to the "best practices" for a low level UART based NFC chip/phy?
- What tools do I need such as (maybe) "neard" or  "nciattach" (which is also not documented at all anywhere) or any other stuff I need?
- Where is the NFC stack userland documentation? How can an application make use of it.